# Common mistakes in the Tefillah

Tags: tefilla, words, shemoneh-esrei, pronunciation, shema

For obvious reasons, one has to be careful to pronounce every word properly in the Tefillah. But I was once taught by a teacher some common mistakes in the pronunciation of some words in the Amidah that completely changed the meaning of the sentence (sometimes to the complete opposite of what it's mean to ask for). Many of these examples would be just changing one letter.

What are some words that must be said extra carefully, that have a totally different meaning if pronounced badly?